# How can I link together outline-mode with RefTeX-TOC?

Tags: emacs, reftex

The question title says it, pretty much.

How can I link together RefTeX's TOC functionality with `outline-mode` such that I can fold sections/subsections/etc.?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Outline) help?

Comment: @giordano Not quite, it would seem.  I tested out the baked-in functionality you linked to, but it would not fold `\subsection`s under `\section`s, as I would have expected.  (Am I confusing `outline-mode` with `org-mode`?)

Comment: `org-mode` is something like `outline-mode` on steroids `:-)`  How do you expect `\subsection`s to be folded?

Comment: @giordano has hit the nail on the head -- i.e., we need the beginning and ending regexp of the region you want to fold.

Comment: @giordano Consider `\section`s `S` and `\subsection`s `o` (continuing the pattern down the hierarchy): `SooSooooSoSooo` could be folded into `S...SooooSoSooo` or `S...S...SoS...`, etc.  To establish the pattern: `CSSooSooSSoo` -> `CSS...S...SS...` -> `C...`.  (where each `...` is an `org`-like continuation line)

Answer (score 2):

**INITIAL DRAFT** (February 19, 2014):   First rough draft.

**EDIT** (February 20, 2014):  Consolidated both functions into just one.  Added a variable `beg-flag-regexp` and revised the logic of the function in relation thereto.  The function now examines the beginning regexp to determine the matching ending regexp; and, it will work with the format of `\begin{anything}` and `\end{anything}` -- provided (of course) that *anything* is the same for both *begin* and *end*.  The function now takes into consideration the possibility that there may be several occurrences on the same line matching the `beg-flag-regexp` -- e.g., `\begin{minipage}\begin{singlespace*}` -- i.e., selection is based upon proximity to the cursor position.

---

The following is a demonstration of how code folding works in Emacs.  Code folding requires that there be a defined regexp for the *beginning* **and** *ending* of the folded region.

```lisp
(defvar beg-flag-regexp (concat
  "\\(\\\\begin\{\\)\\("
  "[^}]*"
  "\\)\\(\}\\)" )
"Regexp matching the beginning of the folded region.")

(defun toggle-block ()
"When FLAG is non-nil, hide the region.  Otherwise make it visible.  For this
function to work, the cursor must be on the same line as the beginning regexp."
(interactive)
  (require 'outline)
  (cond
    ((or
        ;; sweet-spot
        (looking-at beg-flag-regexp)
        ;; point could be between backslash and before the letter n
        (let ((line-begin (save-excursion (beginning-of-line 1) (point))))
          (save-excursion
            (re-search-backward "\\\\" line-begin t)
            (looking-at beg-flag-regexp)))
        ;; point could be to the right of \begin
        (let ((line-begin (save-excursion (beginning-of-line 1) (point))))
          (save-excursion
            (re-search-backward "\\\\begin" line-begin t)
            (looking-at beg-flag-regexp)))
        ;; point could be to the left of \begin
        (let ((line-end (save-excursion (end-of-line 1) (point))))
          (save-excursion
            (re-search-forward "\\\\begin" line-end t)
            (backward-char 6)
            (looking-at beg-flag-regexp))))
      (let* (
          (flag (not (get-char-property (match-end 0) 'invisible)))
          (beg (match-end 0))
          end
          (base-flag-match (regexp-quote
            (buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2))))
          (end-flag-match (concat "\\\\end\{" base-flag-match "\}"))
          (go-fish (concat "\\begin\{" base-flag-match "\}"))  )
        (save-excursion
          (if (re-search-forward end-flag-match nil t)
            (progn
              (setq end (point))
              (outline-flag-region beg end flag)
              (cond
                (flag
                  (overlay-put (make-overlay beg end) 'display "\u25be"))
                (t
                  (mapc 'delete-overlay (overlays-in beg end)))))
            (user-error "Error locating an ending match for:  %s." go-fish)))
        (if (> (point) beg)
          (goto-char beg)) ))
    (t
      (message "Sorry, you are not on a line containing the beginning regexp."))))
```

Comment: This is certainly useful to get the job done, but how might I define Emacs-flavored regular expressions to match what needs to be matched?

Comment: My understanding is that AUCTeX has a bunch of gizmos built in to do some folding; however, I have finally liberated myself completely from that package and never really learned it well.  For my example above, I used the most common situation I could think of  (e.g., begin/end anything).  I essentially only do two types of documents -- letters and legal pleadings, so my LaTeX knowledge is somewhat limited.  If you have an example of something that has a specific beginning and a specific ending, then I'd be happy to take a stab at it.  I would need to see it laid out so that I can visualize it.